# Jquery insertAfter html element refactor

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, clone, insertafter

My brain is fried after a long day and was given a task this weekend of inserting a table in our UI using jquery.

I've got some big ugly lines of code that are inserting html elements...  wanted to see if there was a simple way to make this cleaner.  I know I can break it into several lines, but there has to be a best practice:

```
    $('#submitNewTiers').bind('click',function (e) {

    $('<div class="tiersTables"><span><a href="" rel="#overlay">Edit Tiers </a></span><table class="visible" id="newTiersTable"><thead&gr;<tr><th>Range</th><th>List Price</th><th>Quote Price</th><th class="lastTh">Approval?</th></tr></thead></table></div>').insertAfter('div.tiersTables');
    $('<tbody><tr><td>HERE</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody>').insertAfter('#newTiersTable thead');
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you could just put the entire table as a string into a variable, and use 1 `insertAfter();` to put it into the DOM.

I think it's wise to use as few of these calls as possible (`append()`, `prepend()`, `insertAfter()` etc), since they're not cheap performance wise.

Comment: I appreciate your tip as I will have to add dynamic values into the TDs later on, which will necessitate further calls.  However if there are appended values, I can always use $.each.

Answer (score 1):

Place the HTML code inside your HTML document:

```
<div class="tiersTables">
    <span>
        <a href="" rel="#overlay">Edit Tiers </a>
    </span>
    <table class="visible" id="newTiersTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Range</th>
                <th>List Price</th>
                <th>Quote Price</th>
                <th class="lastTh">Approval?</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>HERE</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Hide it with CSS:

```
div.tiersTables { display:none; }
```

Then, on click, show it:

```
$('#submitNewTiers')click(function() {
    $('.tiersTables').show();
});
```

Comment: I like this answer if I am only adding one table however I need to be able to increment the number of tables I display.  So using your suggestion, I would have to create multiple html tables and hide them then show the closest table on click.

Comment: @Robert My suggestion would be this: Have one hidden table from the start (hard-coded into your HTML source code). Then, whenever you need a new table, clone it and append the clone to the DOM (at the desired location). jQuery has a convenient [`clone()` method](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) for that purpose.